# Server side video converter

Tags: video, server-side, flv, converters, mp4

I am setting up a CMS built in PHP, and now i need to add a part where the user can convert a video from FLV to MP4 format. I have searched for scripts and solutions but nothing works. I was ready to pay for the software but "Aviberry" software costs $5000 and "sothinkmedia" does not work properly on Linux servers. If anyone has something that will work for sure I would appreciate all suggestions.

Comment: [Try this](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`mencoder`](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) part of MPlayer should be able to do this, or try [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/). Both can be called from the command line (or from a script) to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try ffmpeg commands in java code or else another solution use Xuggler API, it converts 
     Video files for any extensions.

```
/* Sample Code For converting Videos in server side */

import java.io.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Quality {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    String s = null;

    try {

    // run the Unix "ps -ef" command
        // using the Runtime exec method:
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i /home/praveen/videos/Oracle.mp4 
-vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -f webm /home/praveen/videos/Oracle.webm");
        //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -i /home/praveen/resize
 images/Videos/RaymondMadetoMeasure.mp4 -vcodec libvpx -acodec libvorbis -f webm 
 /home/praveen/resize images/Videos/Raymond.webm");

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
 }
 }
```